# Нужно считать числа с файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть проблема, начал изучать Python, и мне нужно, например:

Есть файл под названием `list.txt`;
В него записаны 4 числа, например:

`10 20 30 5`

Как считать числа с файла и присвоить что: `a=10, b=20, c=30, d=5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**list.txt**

```
10 20 30 5
```

---

**main.py**

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    a, b, c, d = f.read().split()

print('a={}, b={}, c={}, d={}'.format(a, b, c, d))
```

Comment: `a, b, c, d = map(int, f.read().split())`.